# Performance issue in using two java class in single java file

Tags: java

I just wanted to know that is there any performance issue in

1)Using two classes in single java file.

2)Using inner java class.

I want to use it for internal data structure and supporting class.
Also please tell me which one will be better in terms of performance?

Comment: This is premature optimization at its worst. This minor structure will have minimal to no effect on performance, and instead you should concern yourself with real issues, like creating readable, understandable and debuggable code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Maybe they'll like it better coming from you.

Comment: @EricStein: either way, it's a silly question.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels agreed.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the classes source code is in a single Java file or in two separate Java files doesn't have any impact on the byte-code: both lead to exactly the same byte-code.

An inner class is not different from any other class, except it has access to fields and methods of its enclosing class. The impact on performance is, basically, inexistent.

I concur with @EricStein: don't worry about performance before you have a real performance problem. Strive for readability, maintainability and understandability. The standard is to have one top-level class per source file. You should respect this standard.

Comment: So what u suggest for having inner data structure as we use to have in C like struct???

Comment: What do you mean by "inner"? A class is what you use to define data structures in Java. Whether it's a top-level or not, public or not, class is a matter of visibility and design, not a matter of performance. Edit your question and provide a concrete example and question if you want a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't worry about performance until somebody notices a real problem in a production environment. Anything else is premature optimization.

That being said, don't use two top-level classes in a single java file. It's a bad code smell.

Comment: There are cases where using an inner class is justified.

Comment: @Tarik Inner classes are great. I'm worried about two top-level class declarations in a single file, which is legal but terrifying. That's what he's talking about in item 1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between creating two classes in same file and creating inner class.
**Sine java compiler generates different `.class` files for every class irrespective inner class or not.**
So no difference at runtime .

Answer (score 1):

First thing,

I slightly disagree If You are comparing `inner class` and writing two `classes` in a single `file`.

Inner class is bounded to the Outer class as your design specification.

And writing two classes in same `file` is up to you(considering as a personal taste).Obviously vague and welcoming maintenance `issues`.

There is no matter of performance issue,Since once you compile that file a separate `.class`  generates  for each `class.`